# Do malicious requests count towards the free limit of reCaptcha v3?

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

Do malicious requests (e.g., bots) that are indeed detected by Google count towards the free limit of reCaptcha v3 (1000 calls per second or 1000000 calls per month)? I can't find the answer in the [reCAPTCHA Faqs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq). Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes any calls for reCAPTCHA to make an assessment count towards the 1,000,000 free assessments, whether they are legitimate or malicious requests.

https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/pricing

To be clear you are not charged for `grecaptcha.execute` calls from your frontend, which create the reCAPTCHA token
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#programmatically_invoke_the_challenge

You are just charged for calls to `siteverify` or `assessments.create` when you send that token to the reCAPTCHA server for evaluation.